# Scale size PolyhedronData

Tags: graphics3d, curated-data, geometry, polyhedra

How can I plot a truncated cube with size (sqrt(2)-1)? The code I am using is simply

```
PolyhedronData["TruncatedCube"]
```

Comment: And by size you mean what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case *size* means length of each edge:

```
edgeLength = PolyhedronData["TruncatedCube", "EdgeLengths"][[1]];

Graphics3D[
 GeometricTransformation[
  First @ PolyhedronData["TruncatedCube"],
  ScalingTransform[{1, 1, 1} (Sqrt[2] - 1)/edgeLength]
  ]
 ,
 Axes -> True
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: For people like moi who prefer to avoid the use of `GeometricTransformation[]`: `Graphics3D[
 MapAt[# (Sqrt[2] - 1)/edgeLength &, PolyhedronData["TruncatedCube", "Faces"], 1], Axes -> True]`

Comment: @J.M. one could simply use `Scale` too. p.s. Why do you prefer to avoid `GeometricTransformation`?

Comment: What if I need the side of the cube to be `sqrt(2)-1`?

Comment: Yes, but `Scale[]` is like `GeometricTransformation[]` too; in my usual applications, I often apply replacement rules to the coordinates, and `GeometricTransformation[]` does not often play nice with such replacements. Another point against it for me is that `DiscretizeGraphics[]` and `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[]` do not (currently) work with  `GeometricTransformation[]` objects.

Comment: @J.M. good to know, I'm not using them on daily basis so wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @albus, your scaling factor in this case is $6-4\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. How should I include it in the command?

Comment: @albus, did you notice the scaling factor used in Kuba's and my snippet? Replace that.